# Javascript Timed Event/ Image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, events, timed

What I want to program is a timed event that occurs when a person opens a web page. They will get to a page on the website where an image will be displayed for an amount of time (say 10 seconds) and after that amount of time, they can proceed to the next page. Essentially, I want to create an "ad" that the user cannot skip until the duration of time (the 10 seconds) is over. In Weebly, you can insert a file or embed code directly into the website. Would I have to embed the code or could I insert it as a file?

Comment: I would really suggest getting a new teacher if they dont know how they dont know how to implement a javascript timeout method :-) . Read this http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing1

Comment: Ensure that you have a way for the user to close this ad before the alotted time otherwise you are going to loose a lot of visitors. You will need to look at functions like setInterval and setTimeout : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of fancy ways to do this, but for your sake we will keep it simple. see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ck3dc/19/

to set the timer to 10 secounds just change the milliseconds to 10000 like this:

`onload="setTimeout(myFunction, 10000);"`

all it is doing is hiding and showing on a timer

```
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById('image').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('main').style.display = 'inline';   
}
```

Comment: Using the old `onload` attribute imo is not recommended. Using `.addEventListener` with `onDomReady` is better than that and not really that complicated.